# Anybody seen this behavior with Sql Server Reporting Services, a 64bit OS and an Oracle datasource?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, oracleclient, badimageformatexception

I'm working on a Sql Server Reporting Services solution that queries across both a Sql Server data source and an Oracle 10g data source. My dev box is Windows 7 64bit with Sql Server 2008R2 and I'm hosting IIS7 and SSRS on that system for development; using VS.NET for designing the reports.

I have been having errors when running the report where SSRS complains about loading the 32 bit Oracle client in a 64bit process. There a number of threads out there about how to solve that. The thing is, they all come down to making sure you have the 64bit Oracle, client which I do. The weird chain of events I have goes like this:

- Create initial Oracle datasource and wire up report (it works)
- Edit Oracle datasource connection (it stops working with BadImageFormatException 32bit/64bit error message)
- uninstall and reinstall Oracle client (it works)
- Edit Oracle connection again (it stops working with BadImageFormatException 32bit/64bit error message)

So short of reinstalling the client every time I change the connection string I am at a complete loss. Has anybody seen this sort of behavior? And if so what the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally answered here: [SSRS report with 32-bit Oracle Client Not working in 64-Bit Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852472/ssrs-report-with-32-bit-oracle-client-not-working-in-64-bit-environment/33454141#33454141)

This is the second time I configure a similar server, and the second time I spend hours figuring this one out. If for nobody else, I am writing this for the future me. This is for a Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit, 8GB RAM, 300+GB HDD, Intel Xeon CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz, that is running Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 64bit and IIS 7.0 with web applications that use the Oracle Client 32bit connection System.Data.OracleClient

1. Install the 64bit client
2. Change the name of the Oracle inventory directory @ "C:\Program Files\Oracle" to "C:\Program Files\Oracle64"
3. Restart computer and test for connection from SSRS to Oracle
4. Install the 32bit client and specify a different location for its home directory
5. Restart computer and test connection from SSRS to Oracle and from Web Applications to Oracle

I hope this helps my future self and others :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 64 bit Oracle Client. Beware, i had bad experience on having both oracle 32 bit and 64 bit client. I ended up uninstalling 64 bit oracle client and trying to figure out installing SSRS in 32 bit mode on 64bit win7.