# SSRS report with 32-bit Oracle Client Not working in 64-Bit Environment

Tags: reporting-services, bids, oracleclient, badimageformatexception

I have a SSRS report using 32Bit Oracle client build in BIDS 2008, Report is running fine in BIDS (VS 2008) but when deployed to Report Manager on Win2k3 64 Bit Server it is failing with the following error

> "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed."

I have gone through several articles which are suggesting to Enable IIS to 32Bit using `csscript Enable32Biton64 'true'` and `aspnet_regiis-i`,  but problem with this is I have other application that needs 64-bit capabilities so cannot do it.

Please suggest me the way to do it .TIA.

Comment: did u try restarting both IIS and Report Server?

Comment: Thanks for responding Rohith, sorry if my question was confusing , I have gone through the articles on Enabling32on64 but have not implemented it because it might affect other appliations because my IIS is 6 on win3k server, so there is no question of restarting SSRS server . I'm looking for alternative ways to acheive this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Oracle 64-bit client tools on the server, e.g.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Comment: Thanks Mike, I have some other applications that are depending on 32-bit oracle client, can I have 32-64 side-by-side on the server ? will that allow 32-bit users still use 32-bit resources ?

Comment: Great, i will give it a shot and come back. Thanks again.

Comment: Finally it worked. Installed both 32 and 64 bit clients in the box and configured 64 as Oracle Home, other application which is using 32 bit is not working  though, never mind more than half of my purpose is solved ;) .Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the second time I configure a similar server, and the second time I spend hours figuring this one out. If for nobody else, I am writing this for the future me. 
This is for a Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit, 8GB RAM, 300+GB HDD, Intel Xeon CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz, that is running Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 64bit and IIS 7.0 with web applications that use the Oracle Client 32bit connection System.Data.OracleClient

1. Install the 64bit client
2. Change the name of the Oracle inventory directory @ "C:\Program Files\Oracle" to "C:\Program Files\Oracle64"
3. Restart computer and test for connection from SSRS to Oracle
4. Install the 32bit client and specify a different location for its home directory
5. Restart computer and test connection from SSRS to Oracle and from Web Applications to Oracle

I hope this helps my future self and others :)

Answer (score 0):

Please isntall 64 bit oracle, copy tnsnames.ora and reboot the server, I had same issue and it worked fine after doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running from SSRS 2014. Tried to install SSRS 2016 (version 14.0.609.142), same problem. Test connection works OK, but when I want to go on with the configuration I get the message

> This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed

I tried to configure an ODBC connection, and found out that the reporting server only looked in the 32-odbc servers.

Next I installed the newest Oracle 32-bit client (12.2.0.1.0).
Then everything worked fine!!

So even though the error message asks for a 64 driver instead of a 32 bit driver the opposite was actually the case.